# BottomAppBar CircularNotchedRectangle is not centered when margin is added

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bottomnavigationview

I want to implement my own custom BottomAppBar with circular centered notch, rounded borders and margin.
To add a margin to my BottomAppBar I wrap it with Container widget and set margin attribute `margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5)`. The problem is when I do so the circular notch is moved a bit to the right.

BottomAppBar with margin:
[image]

BottomAppBar without margin:
[image]

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(ExampleApp());

class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: ExampleScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(color: Colors.amber,),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        elevation: 2.0,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationView(),
      extendBody: true,
    );
  }
}

class BottomNavigationView extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 5, right: 5),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
        child: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildTabItem(),
              _buildTabItem()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTabItem() {
    return Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 60,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 24),
              Text(''),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is this Flutter SDK bug or my implementation approach is wrong?